# Show that $\frac{S_n}{n} \to 0$ almost surely

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

For the below question:

Suppose that $X_i$ are independent random variables such that $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) \leq c \sqrt{i}$ for some fixed but positive constant $c$. Show that $\displaystyle{\frac{S_n}{n} = \frac{X_1 + \cdots X_n}{n}}$ converges to $0$ a.s.

My first thought was to use Chebychev's Inequality to bound the probability, then apply Borel-Cantelli Lemma. However, it seems in this case that I cannot find a convergent series to bound the probability. Any help would be thankful.

Comment: Do you know the theorem that if $X_i$ are independent, $E(X_i)=0$ and $\sum_i \operatorname{Var}(X_i)<\infty,$ then $\sum_iX_i$ converges a.s.? If so, apply it to the sequence $X_n/n,$ and infer from that that $S_n/n\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: Please notice following fact: if $\{X_n,n\ge 1\}$ are independent r.v.s with $\mathsf{E}X_n=0$, $\mathsf{E}X_n^2=\sigma^2_n$, $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$, $s_n^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2\to\infty$, then $\sum_n\frac{X_n}{s_n^{\alpha}} $ convergence a.s. and
$S_n/s_n^{\alpha} \stackrel{\text{a.s.}}\longrightarrow 0 $ for $ \alpha>\frac12 $.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen can you give a reference? I am often also guilty of not doing what I am now preaching, but it seems to me that you should make your comment into an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JGWang same comment that I made to spaceisdarkgreen: "... I am often also guilty of not doing what I am now preaching, but it seems to me that you should make your comment into an answer."  Thanks!

Comment: @peterag Thank you! That is also what I want to recommend to people who answer this question since the answer is be very nontrivial to me.

Comment: @peterag By the way, I also found the related theorems called Strong LLN and Kolmogorov's Inequality. I think applying these can solve this question

Comment: @Stack_Underflow   Kronecker's lemma also comes up in the solution proposed in the first comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$ \sum_n \operatorname{Var}(X_n/n) \le \sum_n \frac{c}{n^{3/2}} <\infty,$$ so by [Kolmogorov's two-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem), $\sum_n X_n/n$ converges almost surely, so by [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma), $S_n/n\to 0.$

---

On a side note, in addition to the proof in the link above, the two-series theorem is immediate from the [martingale convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems), since if $E(Z_n)=0$ and $\sum_n \operatorname{Var}(Z_n)<\infty,$ then $M_n = \sum_{k\le n} Z_k$ is an $L^2$-bounded martingale.

Comment: +1, just learned about this theorem in the past week! the frequency illusion at work (was wondering whether the harmonic series with terms randomly set to positive or negative would converge)

Comment: Instead of $n$ , we can take any monotonic sequence $a_{n}\to\infty$ . Then if $\sum_{n}\text{Var}(\frac{X_{n}}{a_{n}})<\infty$ then $\frac{S_{n}-E(S_{n})}{a_{n}}\xrightarrow{a.s} 0$ .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Yes, the question is suboptimal in the sense that we can just as easily show, e.g. $S_n/n^a\to 0$ a.s. for $a>3/4.$